# iTextSharp trims leading space and causes misalignment of columns

Tags: itext

When moving from the versions 4.1.2 => 5.1.3 of iTextSharp I have come across a bug that happens when generating a PDF from text.  The problem is that when the first character of a line has a leading spaces then that leading space gets truncated.  This is a problem with a  right justified columns.

Example: (dashes= spaces)

*Input*:

> ------Header
>   --------------1
>   --------------2
>   0123456789

*Output*:

> -----Header
>   -------------1
>   -------------2
>   **0123456789**    ~~~Notice improper alignment because this column did not have leading space!

The problematic code has been narrowed down to the file "iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfChunck.cs"  method "TrimFirstSpace". 
This method is called from the PdfDocument class while streaming out the bytes.  The problem is that there is no code comments as to what this method trying to be accomplish.

What should I change to make this work right?  It seems like commenting out the ELSE condition in here should fix this.

```
public float TrimFirstSpace()
{
    BaseFont ft = font.Font;
    if (ft.FontType == BaseFont.FONT_TYPE_CJK && ft.GetUnicodeEquivalent(' ') != ' ')
    {
            if (value.Length > 1 && value.StartsWith("\u0001"))
            {
                value = value.Substring(1);
                return font.Width('\u0001');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (value.Length > 1 && value.StartsWith(" "))
            {
                value = value.Substring(1);
                return font.Width(' ');
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Using spaces for padding is wrong. We won't fix this.

Comment: Wrong according to who?  iTextSharps #1 goal is to take input and convert it to PDF no matter what type characters it is.  Thinking like that is flawed and unfounded.  BTW you already figured out you were doing it wrong.  Answer will be posted now.

Comment: I didn't notice you were moving from a version that was 4 years old to a version that was a year and a half old. I always assume that people upgrade to the latest version. I mistook this for another issue that was similar, but not a bug. I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Newer code changes address the issue.  The if statement is important.

**OLD**

```
chunk = overflow;
chunk.TrimFirstSpace();
```

**New**

```
bool newlineSplit = chunk.IsNewlineSplit();
chunk = overflow;
if (!newlineSplit)
    chunk.TrimFirstSpace();
```

http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/518/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfDocument.cs#l415