# Lost spaces in my created pdfs (pdfbox & itextpdf)

Tags: java, indentation, pdfbox, itextpdf

I'm using pdfbox & itextpdf to create very simple invoices in pdf format.

We're creating raw invoice text files in an erp system outside of java - so the only thing i have to do combining the textfile with a (pdf) template. (Thats not the problem. ;) )

It's working fine - but I found now an indentation error in the pdf: After the header of the table, the indentation goes wrong (**one leading whitespace is removed**).

What I'm doing wrong?

Thats the code, producing the sample pdf:

```
final File outputFile = this.createTmpFile();
final Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
document.open();
final StringBuffer testText = new StringBuffer();
testText.append("                                                                 21.12.2012\n");
testText.append("\n");
testText.append("\n");
testText.append("\n");
testText.append("Invoice\n");
testText.append("\n");
testText.append("\n");
testText.append("Amount  Description                                         CUR       Price\n");
testText.append("===========================================================================\n");
testText.append("\n");
testText.append(" 1      Order #E41141454 from 01.01.2012:                   EUR       21,21\n");
testText.append("        nice text, nice text, nice text, nice text,\n");
testText.append("        nice text, nice text, nice text, nice text,\n");
testText.append("\n");
testText.append("        Status: online\n");
final Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
para.setFont(new Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 8.6f));
para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_UNDEFINED);
para.setLeading(1.2f, 1.2f);
final String t = testText.toString();
para.add(t);
document.add(para);
document.close();
```

[image: SampleInvoice]

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981437/itextsharp-trims-leading-space-and-causes-misalignment-of-columns (a problem that was solved in a recent version; you should mention which version of iText you're using)

Comment: Yes, it could be the same cause. The version was itextpdf 5.0.6 - I switched to 5.4.0 and it works fine now. But I think, were created round about one million pdfs in the last year - we would have to see the missalignment in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**!

We updated from itextpdf **5.0.6** to **5.4.0**